# c# mvc using @ajax.ActionLink how to call modelpopup

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Please Help me How can i call Bootstrap modelpopup using Ajax
Here is my code

```
 @Ajax.ActionLink("CheckOut", "EditMasterDatadetails", "Home", new { Id = _objMaster.Id },
new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "GET",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "myModal",
    OnBegin = "OpenEditDialog()",
    OnComplete = "ShowPopup",   
}, new {
    @class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg",
    @id = "chkOut"
})
<div class="modal fade showModal" id="myModal" role="dialog">
</div>
```

My Jquery part

```
 function ShowPopup() {          
            alert('Hello');
        }
```

Comment: Code seems good, make sure to check script registration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7501958/728795

Comment: no use im getting Error as OpenEditDialog un defind

Comment: that means your `ShowPopup` script is defined improperly. how do you add it to the page?